# f2py: Python does not import module

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I would like to import an Fortran module into python with `f2py`.

I successfully compiled the module with the command `f2py -c primes.f90 -m primes`.

This command generates `primes.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` and an directory:

```
primes
--.lib
----libprimes.E32HNUCUWH2OOA5WTEOFP7BSXKY3WIRC.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
```

When I am trying to import the module as described [here](https://www.numfys.net/howto/F2PY/) with `import primes` it imports something but not the module. So e.g I cannot see the docstring or access the functions.

I suspect that Python tries to import the folder 'primes' and not the module itself.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have used the example from [here](https://www.numfys.net/howto/F2PY/) to demonstrate the problem:

My Python code to showcase the problem:

```
import primes

print(primes) 
print(primes.__doc__) # should return "This module 'primes' is auto-generated with f2py (version:2). Functions: [...]"
print(type(primes)) # as @VladimirF mentioned should return fortran
print(primes.logical_to_integer.__doc__) # should return "prime_numbers = logical_to_integer(is_prime,num_primes,[n]) Wrapper for ``logical_to_integer``. [...]"
```

Actual return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx", line 6, in <module>
    print(primes.logical_to_integer.__doc__)
AttributeError: module 'primes' has no attribute 'logical_to_integer'
<module 'primes' (namespace)>
None
<class 'module'>
```

**Edit 1**

I have followed up the suggestion of @roygvib. I have tried several versions of python and conda and part of the problem seems the be that I was using the systems interpreter for compiling the module and the conda for running the python code.

For all the other combinations the following exception is raised:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing primes: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

can be translated to:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing primes: The given Module was not found.
```

So the actual error was that no error was raised in the given combination.

Comment: What exactly does it import? What exactly happens? What object do you have? It should be of type `fortran`. Does it have type `fotran`? If yes, all is correct.

Comment: Have you tried the example mentioned under "Getting Started" in the link you referred to?

Comment: @jack yes I have. That also does not work for me.

Comment: @VladimirF I hope my edit helps.

Comment: Did you want `logical_to_integer` instead of `locical_for_integer`?

Comment: Yes I did, but the result does not change. It generates still the same output.

Comment: Maybe you have mixed the module name `primes` and `module`? The argument `f2py -c module.f90 -m <MODULE_NAME>` needs to be the same when in the python REPL `>>> import <MODULE_NAME>>`. I'm not sure if `module` is a reserved keyword. Best if you just try it out with `primes`.

Comment: I am sorry. First I tried to describe the problem in a general way, since I think that  this problem is not dependent on the code itself. After the comments I edited my question with a specific example. Module was meant as a general term. I now edited my question that hopefully all code represents the specific case.

Comment: possibly some version mismatch of "f2py" and "python"? (if so, using a specific version like "python3.8 -m numpy.f2py -c primes.f90 -m primes" ... and "$ python3.8" might help?)

Comment: Just to confirm - this is in python3 on windows and you have a mingw or cygwin gfortran compiler installed?

Comment: @cup Yes I am working on Windows 10 with python 3.8 and I have mingw installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from @zlamere from [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16416) github issue worked for me.

instead of `f2py -c primes.f90 -m primes` I used `python -m numpy.f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 primes.f90 -m primes`

I don't know why this command works and the other one doesn't.